Why is the API_KEY from .env File Undefined After Publishing My VS Code Extension?
I'm developing a VS Code extension, and during the development phase, I was able to successfully retrieve the API_KEY defined in a .env file using process.env
During development, I used the dotenv package to load the environment variables from the .env file, and I could access the API_KEY without any issues.
After publishing the extension to the VS Code Marketplace, the API_KEY returned undefined. The .env file was included during the packaging process, but it seems the environment variable is not accessible in the published version.
published Extension Developer Tools
Is there a way to load environment variables from a .env file or securely store and access the API_KEY in a published VS Code extension? I want to avoid hardcoding the API key directly in my extension code.
What are the best practices for handling sensitive information like API keys in a VS Code extension, especially after publishing?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79130952
